# ocaml pretty printer (code formatter)

Tags: ocaml

I am looking for a code formatter or pretty printer for ocaml. Something like gofmt for the go programming language. It should preferably preserve comments.

I am correcting hand-ins and some of the code is formatted in a way that makes it very hard to read.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you don't care about comments, you can use camlp4:

```
camlp4 <file> -parser o -printer o > <new-file>
```

Or you can use external indenter tools, as [ocp-indent](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent).

Comment: Actually, that seemed to preserve comments. Thank you!

Comment: You might also want to include the way to do with the revised syntax. I needed it for use with the Camlp4 lexer parser.

Answer (score 0):

These days [ocamlformat is recommended](https://ocaml.org/docs/formatting-your-code) and well integrated into dune with `dune fmt`.