# Ocaml formatting tool

Tags: formatting, ocaml, indentation

The problem is quite simple, i have a pretty messy ocaml code, with wrong indentation, break line ecc.
is there any tool to format a ocaml code properly?

thanks!

Comment: This is an apparent duplicate of: [ocaml pretty printer (code formatter)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12798723/487781).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ocp-indent](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent) either in you editor or as an external tool to indent your code. It should work on windows.

Comment: Note: `ocp-indent` only does code indentation, not full blown code formatting. For example, it will not change positions of `->` inside a match.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Emacs with [TypeRex extension](http://www.typerex.org/).
I don't use Emacs everyday, but use it to indent my code, it's a very good tool !

Comment: The problem is that I'm working on Windows

Comment: It's not very convenient for a daily workflow, but if you don't need to convert such code often, consider using Linux in a VirtualBox.